# Discrepancy between MSS sent by client and MSS received by host

Tags: tcp, network-programming, wireshark

When the client initiates the connection with the SYN bit set, Wireshark (and TCPDump) show the MSS as being 1460. However, when the same packet is delivered to the host, Wireshark (and TCPDump) show the MSS as being 1416.

Can anybody please explain why there's a discrepancy of 44 bytes?

The image below shows the MSS received by the host. Sorry but I don't have a screenshot showing the client's initial SYN 1460 MSS.

During actual data transfer, the 1416 is used as an MSS (1404 for payload and 12 for options such as the TSVal)

My original thought was that it has something to do with Path MTU discovery, and that some space is being reserved for any additional headers that may be added on while the packet is making it's way from the sender to the destination. Am I correct in thinking so? If so, is there a way to find a breakdown of how these are being used?

[image: MSS received on host]

Comment: The one you see with 1416, is it the SYN received or a SYN/ACK sent by that node?

Comment: SYN received from the other node.

Comment: Can you show the raw result of tcpdump and wireshark in both nodes? Are client and server in the same LAN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting the university's network admin, we concluded that that a lower MSS was being imposed by the network for load reasons.